# appendChild in IE6/IE7 does not work with existing elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, appendchild

I have a div that needs to be moved from one place to another in the DOM. So at the moment I am doing it like so:

```
flex.utils.get('oPopup_About').appendChild(flex.utils.get('oUpdater_About'));
```

But, IE, being, well, IE, it doesn't work. It works all other browsers, just not in IE.

I need to do it this way as the element (div) **'oUpdater_About'** needs to be reused as it is populated over and over.

So i just need to be able to move the div around the DOM, appendChild will let this happen in all browsers, but, IE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: appendChild has always worked in IE for me. Are you sure that "flex.utils.get" is returning an actual DOM Element node, rather than some library-specific node-like object?

Comment: Definitely, that is just a wrapper for a document.getElementById script. I have tried to replace it with document.getElementById, same problem. Could the issue be that I am not creating the element on the fly? That it already exists in the DOM onload. In theory it shouldn't! But you know IE.

Comment: I've never come across this problem; IE has always worked correctly for me, removing the element from its existing parent and appending it to the new parent. Try getting both nodes into variables before doing the append so you can use alert() (or your preferred debugging tool), just to be sure you're getting what you think you're getting.

Comment: One more thing: if the element you are trying to append to is a table, I believe IE forces you to explicitly find the tbody element and append to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the node first, before you can append it anywhere else.
One node cannot be at two places at the same time.

```
var node = flex.utils.get('oUpdater_About')
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
flex.utils.get('oPopup_About').appendChild(node);
```

Comment: Are you serious? that is wacky! you don't need to do that with regular DOM manipulation.  Does the flex wrapper call the same code in IE vs. Other browsers underneath?

Comment: @scunliffe: I found no clues to wether you can or cannot re-append a node that is already appended somewhere in the DOM.
Do you have a source that could clear that up for me?

Comment: i had a ajax loop that will call appendChild for each of my child nodes (even if not actually moved to different parent node). my memory leak in IE is solved simply by calling removeChild first.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to clone the oUpdater_About (with node.cloneNode(true))
this way you get a copy and can reuse the dom-snippet as often as you want (in any browser)

Comment: I think you may have missed the part where sparkyfield said he wanted to  *move* elements, not *copy* them.

Comment: That's it Jason, cloning the element will mean I have clashing ids, and element. I need one element, to be moved around, not copied.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post tends to suggest that there is indeed a problem with appendChild with respect to this:

http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com/2007/01/ie-7-appendchild-bug.html

Have you tried cloning it, removing it, then inserting the clone instead?

James

Comment: Yeah, this is another fun one in IE. You must append TRs to a TBODY in IE.  Attempting to append them directly to the TABLE will fail.