# Internet explorer and removeChild()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, removechild

I have been using `elem.removeChild()` to remove elements from my document, but saving a JavaScript reference to that element, so that I can add them back when appropriate.  Works just fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Now I notice that that on IE7, those elements get destroyed in the process, having all their children removed.  When I add them back to the same parent element, they are the same type of element and have retained things like their class name, but they have no children elements.

Is this expected behavior?  I know I can change my app to do things differently, but it would take a good couple hours of reworking and I'd obviously like to avoid that.  I've always assumed that it is ok to remove elements, either by using `removeChild()` or by setting the parent's `innerHTML` to an empty string,  and as long as I had a reference to the element (i.e. a variable points to the element, not just an element id), it was ok to add and remove elements freely without having the element messed up.

Is this a bug with IE, am I somehow confused and something else is going on, or is this known and expected behavior?

Comment: Expect the unexpected with Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: The spec for removeChild doesn't explicitly say that the children of the node being removed should be kept along with that node, although to me it seems logical that they should and obviously that is what the FF and Chrome developers decided too. I don't know what the spec says to do if the parent's innerHTML is set to an empty string, but in my opinion that way is a bit like saying "wipe over whatever was there" so in that case I think it is reasonable for the browser to throw away everything that was in that innerHTML even if there were references in code to some of the removed elements.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'd accept your answer if it wasn't a comment.  Turns out removeChild doesn't really destroy the element, only setting innerHTML to '' does.

Comment: @rob - I didn't really think my comment was good enough to be an answer, but if it helped you enough that you want to accept it - well, I've now made it an answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn well its better than anything else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec for removeChild doesn't explicitly say that the children of the node being removed should be kept along with that node, although to me it seems logical that they should and obviously that is what the FF and Chrome developers decided too. I don't know what the spec says to do if the parent's innerHTML is set to an empty string, but in my opinion that way is a bit like saying "wipe over whatever was there" so in that case I think it is reasonable for the browser to throw away everything that was in that innerHTML even if there were references in code to some of the removed elements.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your implementation, I'm not sure you'll get more than blind answers; here's one:

Do you happen to be working with table rows? Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232410/appendchild-in-ie6-ie7-does-not-work-with-existing-elements/1232521#1232521)
. Apparently `<tr>` has to attach to `<tbody>` in IE, rather than directly to a `<table>`.

Comment: If you add some `code` to your question, I may be able to answer it.

Comment: Yeah I think its been solved, setting innerHTML to '' does more than remove elements from the document, it destroys their contents. (on IE only).  Thanks though.